# Modifying Zend_ViewHelper_Pagination_Controller Partial-Path

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination, partial-views, viewhelper

I've got a Zend-Framework application. I'm using the module-structure which `Zend_Controller_Front`provides. Here is a small excerpt from my directory-structure (only the important parts for this question):

```
root-directory
- modules
  - blog
    - views
      - scripts
        - index_index.phtml
- views
  - pagination_control.phtml
```

As you can see I've got view-scripts that are specific to a module/controller/action. These views are located in the corresponding path (in this case like `modules/blog/views`. I've also got a more general view-directory located in the root-direcetory of my application.

What I am doing now is to call the `PaginationControl`-ViewHelper in `modules/blog/views/scripts/index_index.phtml`. This View-Helper however renders a partial-view, as you know. The ViewHelper tries to locate the  partial-view within the same directory (meaning `modules/blog/views/scripts`. Since I want to use the same view-partial-script (`pagination_control.phtml`) in different modules I want to make this view-partial accessable from each module. So I want to put that file in the general `views`-folder in the root-directory.

However this doesn't work. The ViewHelper always looks for the view-script in the corresponding module-folder.

Anyone can help to make it accessable from my general `views`-directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-4233), since ZF 1.6.2 pagination control can take an **array** instead of a string for the partial argument, and in this array you set 1st the name of the partial and in 2nd the module name. This is still **undocumented**.

Using an array you can specify a module  ('common'?) for the partial to use.

The real call will be (with **$partial your 3rd argument to the paginationControl()** view helper ):

```
$this->view->partial($partial[0], $partial[1], $pages);
```

This is usefull if you have a 'common' module.

Now here you are using a shared folder. You shoudl have installed it as a shared folder for your Zend_View this way (in a Boostrap or ressource code):

```
$view->addScriptPath("/root-directory/views");
```

or better:

```
$view->addScriptPath("/root-directory/views/partials");
```

And then you should'nt be required to specify any module directory. Zend_View should always check for a partial in this folder.

Comment: Thank you very much. I only tested the second method since it's that, what I want to achieve. I'm not that fan of a common module. So 2nd methods goes for me :)